# Why isn't div circle not appearing with DOM style manipulation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Want a circle to appear in my browser with the color listed in the `sampleClr` variable, however, the circle does not show at all. I have tried hard coding a color in place of `sampleClr` in the function:

```
gamePiece.style.backgroundColor = sampleClr;
```

However, it still does not work. I have included my entire code below. Any input as to what I am doing wrong?

```js
let sampleClr = "blue"

const gamePiece = document.querySelector(#gamePiece);

gamePiece.style.backgroundColor = sampleClr;
```

```css
#gamePiece {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <title>Connect 4</title>
  <link href="Test.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="gamePiece"> </div>

  <script src="Test.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work -

```js
let sampleClr = "blue"

const gamePiece = document.querySelector('#gamePiece');

gamePiece.style.backgroundColor = sampleClr;
```

```css
#gamePiece {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Connect 4</title>
    <link href="Test.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="gamePiece"> </div>

    <script src="Test.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

It was just a minor error - you had to put the parameter given to querySelector as a string(with quotes) and with that change it works.

You could have also used `document.getElementById('gamePiece')` since you are selecting an element through its id and directly have a selector specifically for it. It's just an alternative. Both will work the same.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to work on this habit with querySelector.

Comment: will do. Looks like I have to wait a few more minutes before I can accept

Answer (score 1):

In the query selector, the argument should always be a string. You set the argument to `#gamePiece` when it had to be `'#gamePiece'`. This should work:

```js
let sampleClr = "blue"

const gamePiece = document.querySelector('#gamePiece');

gamePiece.style.backgroundColor = sampleClr;
```

```css
#gamePiece {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Connect 4</title>
  <link href="Test.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="gamePiece"> </div>

<script src="Test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```